# How to install php gd library on backtrack 5 r3

Tags: php, gd, backtrack-linux

I have a problem when resizing an image on php, it says install gd library. I researched on the internet but I couldn't find something to fix that kind of problem and I tried your post as well but there is no apt-get install php5-gd in backtrack 5r3.

Comment: What does `phpinfo();` says about gd? Is jpeg support enabled? You will need this to resize the images.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the gd2.dll in your php.ini

```
;Windows Extensions
;Note that ODBC support is built in, so no dll is needed for it.
;
extension=php_gd2.dll
```

Comment: Backtrack is a linux versions you don't need any .dll files

Comment: view page [http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/coffee-lounge/37811-does-linux-use-dlls.html].

Comment: Lakshay see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538635/possible-to-use-a-dll-on-linux

Comment: I placed php_gd2.dll in php.ini. When I check php configuration, I could not see gd library install. 
I also downloaded a zip file 'libgd-2.1.0-alpha1' and tried to install, it shows a file path "/backup/gdlib/libgd-2.1.0-alpha1 " in PHP Environment. Still I faced same problem.